# Chromebook Recovery Utility won't recognize model number

Tags: chromebook

I have an Acer Chromebook 11 (CB3-111). It's hardware class is
`GNAWTY C2A-E7J-Q8Q`. I am currently running Chrome OS version 7834.70.0. I am attempting to create a recovery SD card. I entered the hardware class by clicking on it in step one in of the Chromebook Recovery Utility process. It says `No model found yet. Keep typing.`.

The model number has been recognized before, so what could possibly by happening now? If the box uses autocomplete, then it's not working now, either.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, the model used to be there but no longer. But from my working chromebook (CB3-111) it leads me to download the recovery of Acer Chromebook 11 (C730 / C730E). Give it a try if you still have it.

Comment: Maybe I’m just dense, but — give *what* a try? What is the answer?

Comment: Choose Acer Chromebook 11 (C730 / C730E) from the drop down list can create the recovery media. This should be the same image as CB3-111